# Safe way to fetch img from a path ? PHP(PDO)

Tags: php, image, path, src

is there something secure way to fecth an image ?, my code does like this `<img src="$file_destination">` // $file_destination saved on db.

Is there way like `urlencode` version in `img src` ? Or only **Validation** is ok ? Give me some easy to understand tips. Thank you very much.

Comment: It really depends on what kind of validation you are referring to. The HTTP server wont serve paths in invalid locations.

Comment: what do you mean, I can't seem to follow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<img src="$file_destination">
```

Just go ahead and print that on your screen, what safety would you like to achieve from that?

You can probably try to make sure there is no XSS stuff in there but that should be done where you are saving that path to the database.

You don't even need to urlencode image path. As long as it is valid it will work fine.

Comment: so the safety measure comes in the file destination which is save in the database?

Comment: Yes you should validate the file when you save it on your server and not keep an unsafe file and just validate its path